# Haxe get function parameter type

Tags: reflection, haxe

I have haxe code like this:

```
var fn:String->Int = function(s:String):Int{
    return 1;
}

getParameterType(fn,1);//Should return String as it is first parameter of fn
```

what should function getParameterType code look like?

Comment: hi i want to ask you something regard haxe.. can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Haxe Reflection APIs can be found here: [Reflect](http://haxe.org/api/reflect) and [Type](http://haxe.org/api/type).

Looking through them, there doesn't seem to be any way to check the types of arguments on functions, probably because this information isn't available at runtime on many of the platforms.  Javascript for instance is loosely typed, and the information you are looking for is not included by default.

So you have three options:

1. Use [RTTI](http://haxe.org/doc/advanced/rtti) (Run Time Type Info).  If a class is marked with `@:rtti` metadata (in Haxe 3, or if it `implements haxe.rtti.Infos` in Haxe 2), then information about that class, including the types of function parameters, is available in Xml format at run time.  You will have to look at the Xml to figure out what the argument is.  This will only work for functions which are attached to classes though, it won't work for anonymous functions.
2. Use macros.  This is outside the scope of my answer, but maybe ask on the Haxe mailing list if you need help :)  If the argument type is known at compile time, it can be made known to macros, and you can probably save that information back somewhere so it is available at run time.
3. Figure out another usage that doesn't require you to know the type :)

Of course, if you only need the information at compile-time, not at run-time, you can do: `$type(fn)` anywhere in your code and when you compile it will let you know the exact type signature of "fn".

Comment: hi i want to ask you something regard haxe.. can you help me?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I see you've asked in a few places :P  Just post a question and tag it `haxe` and hopefully someone can help you. Otherwise there is Haxe IRC channel or the Haxe mailing list.